# AST generation for a an application developed both in visual basic and c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, abstract-syntax-tree, call-graph

I'm currently understanding one application developed both in visual basic and c#. Running through the code is getting tough as code is around 50KLOC. So I'm planning for generation of AST (abstract syntax tree). Will it be possible to generate for both language together.

At least a call graph generation will be helpful (but can't find any tool which works for both languages)

Please let me know if this question is confusing.

Thanks in Advance
Dev

Answer (score 1):

Generation of ASTs won't do anything to help you understand the code, [unless you also add huge amounts of analysis and display machinery](http://www.semdesigns.com/products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html).  This will take you months to build if you are extremely good at this kind of thing.

You are better off getting an off-the-shelf tool to help you understand the code, if your goal is to get on with understanding/enhancing it.